# This is my ceasar cipher but line 22 is wrong. No string found

Tags: python

This is my Caesar cipher which i am making. i am having some troubles with 'substrings'. The error code says that there is no substring found on line 22 and i don't know how to fix it. please help.

```
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    La = len(alphabet)
    message = input("Insert your message: ")
    key = int(input("Insert your key: "))
    cipher = ''

    for A in message:
        if A in alphabet:
            cipher += alphabet[(alphabet.index(A)+key)%La]
        else:
            print ("Error")
    print(cipher)

    cipher2 = ''

    question = input("Do you wish to decrypt?: ")

    if question == "Y" or "y":
        for A in message:
            if A in alphabet:
                print(cipher.index(A))
                cipher2 += cipher[(cipher.index(A)+key)%La]
            else:
                print ("Error")
        print(cipher)
    else:
        print("Thank you")
```

Comment: Not to your question, but `if question == "Y" or "y"` will always evaluate to `True`.  I believe you mean `if question in ("Y", "y")` or `if question.lower() == 'y'`.

Comment: `cipher2 += cipher[(cipher.index(A)+key)%La]` should probably be `cipher2 += cipher[(cipher.index(A)+key)%len(cipher)]`

Comment: Why do you loop over the original message when decrypting?

Comment: Why do you add the key when encrypting and then add it again when decrypting.  Should you add it in on case and subtract it in another?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few errors in the program.  The immediate problem is that your second loop steps through the original message, rather than the cipher.  Change line 19 to read:

```
for A in cipher:
```

This will get you to the next error, the index out of range when you try to decrypt the individual letter.

This is not the place for speculative debugging.  I recommend that you find yourself a debugging tutorial at your level, perhaps with the search phrase "How do I debug my program?"

For starters, when you have an execution error you don't understand, de-construct the problem statement and "ask the patient where it hurts."  For instance your original code

```
for A in message:
    if A in alphabet:
        print(cipher.index(A))
```

... becomes ...

```
for A in message:
    print "CHECKPOINT 1", message, A
    if A in alphabet:
        print "CHECKPOINT 2", cipher
        A_pos = cipher.index(A)
        print "CHECKPOINT 3", A_pos
        print(cipher.index(A))
```

Try it with your decryption statement:

```
        decode_pos = A_pos + key
        print "CHECKPOINT 4", decode_pos
        decode_pos %= La
        print "CHECKPOINT 5", decode_pos, len(cipher)
        clear_char = cipher[decode_pos]
        print "CHECKPOINT 6", clear_char
        cipher2 += clear_char
        print "CHECKPOINT 7", cipher2
```

Does this get you moving?  It's heavy-handed, but effective.